# VS 2022 - Diagnostic Tools failed unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, debug-diagnostic-tool

I have a problem with the current version of Microsoft Visual Studio Version 17.0.0. 
Every time I start debugging my project the the Diagnostic Tools give me the following error:
`The diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly. The Diagnostics Hub output in the Output window may contain additional information.`

 
Additional information from the Output window: 
`Request to DataWarehouse host was unsuccessful: 'Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'`

 
None of my projects is using SQLite. So this seems to be an internal problem in VS. 
It worked fine for me in VS 16.x.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else finds this later:

I am using VS 17.2.0 Preview 2.1 right now, and the bug seems to be fixed.
I can not tell you, from wich version on it is (or will be) fixed in the non-Preview builds.